# ubuntu-xboxdrv creates 4 controllers automatically. How do I get rid of them?

Tags: 14.04

I use a wired Xbox 360 controller with Ubuntu, and although it works fine when plugged in with applications that let you select your controller, other applications like `ppsspp` default to js1, which is a blank controller.

Is there a way to make it so `ubuntu-xboxdrv` doesn't create these wireless controllers?

[image: 4 Controllers]

Comment: Why are you using ubuntu-xboxdrv? Is there a problem with the regular xboxdrv package?

Comment: Apart from it breaking the suspend feature whenever I use it, no.

Comment: I think you should use regular xboxdrv. ubuntu-xboxdrv is an unofficial modified version of xboxdrv, so I doubt you'll get help with it here on Ask Ubuntu. Install regular xboxdrv and see if maybe that solves your problem. If it doesn't, don't switch back to ubuntu-xboxdrv. (For when you install xboxdrv, you may get a newer version by adding the official PPA with the command "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:grumbel/ppa". Use that and run "sudo apt-get update" before removing ubuntu-xboxdrv and installing xboxdrv.)

Comment: Alright, thanks. If you add that to an answer I can reward the bounty to you.

Comment: Here is an explanation how to solve: https://askubuntu.com/questions/695069/xbox-controller-blinking/1438948#1438948

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use regular xboxdrv instead of ubuntu-xboxdrv. ubuntu-xboxdrv is an unofficial modified version of xboxdrv, so I doubt you'll get help with it here on Ask Ubuntu. Install regular xboxdrv and see if maybe that solves your problem. If it doesn't, don't switch back to ubuntu-xboxdrv. (For when you install xboxdrv, you may get a newer version by adding the official PPA with the command "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:grumbel/ppa". Use that and run "sudo apt-get update" before removing ubuntu-xboxdrv and installing xboxdrv.)