# XBox Controller blinking

Tags: kernel, xbox-360, joystick

I've connected a XBox Wireless Controller for PC with my ubuntu machine. Everything works fine and all js0-3 devices in /dev/input/ are available.

But normally the circle in the middle of the controller should show the device id (1-4), which isn't shown. The circle is only blinking. I tryed that in Windows and everything works fine. Also the wired XBox Controller has no problems to show its id.

Anybody know, why this doesn't work? Are there some kernel modules, which must be enabled?

[image: Xbox Controller]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](https://www.microsoft.com/hardware/_base_v1//products/xbox-360-wireless-controller-for-windows/gm_xboxcw_liquidblk_otherviews01.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 solutions you have for solving this:

1) Install steamos xpad patch: http://ppa.launchpad.net/mdeslaur/steamos/ubuntu/pool/main/s/steamos-xpad-dkms/

2) Install Xboxdrv:

2.1) Easy installation for Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:rael-gc/ubuntu-xboxdrv
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-xboxdrv
```

2.2) Without using other repos:

```
sudo apt-get install xboxdrv
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe/blacklist.conf
```

Add "blacklist xpad" to the end of the file, and reboot. Afterwards to start xboxdrv just type in "sudo xboxdrv --silent --mimic-xpad" in terminal.

Comment: Following the second option Ubuntu still not able to find my xbox controller

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for **Ubuntu 22.04** is to follow these steps:

1. Install xboxdrv:

`$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:rael-gc/ubuntu-xboxdrv`

`$ sudo apt-get update`

`$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-xboxdrv`

2. Add xpad in the blacklist:

`$ echo "blacklist xpad" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

`$ sudo rmmod xpad`         (Unload the module if it's already loaded)

3. Remove `jstest-gtk` to set `xboxdrv` as default:

`$ sudo apt-get purge jstest-gtk`

`$ sudo apt-get install xboxdrv`

`$ sudo apt-get install jstest-gtk` (Reinstalling it without affecting `xboxdrv`)

4. In the directory `/etc/default/`, make a new file called "xboxdrv" with the following text in it:

```c
[xboxdrv]
silent = true

# controller 1
trigger-as-button = true
dpad-as-button = true
deadzone = 4000

# controller 2
next-controller = true
trigger-as-button = true
dpad-as-button = true
deadzone = 4000

# controller 3
next-controller = true
trigger-as-button = true
dpad-as-button = true
deadzone = 4000

# controller 4
next-controller = true
trigger-as-button = true
dpad-as-button = true
deadzone = 4000

[xboxdrv-daemon]
dbus = disabled
```

5. To start `xboxdrv` every time when Ubuntu boots, follow the steps of `systemctl` in [this website](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112920/xboxdrv-not-able-to-start/1438836#1438836). It's not necessary to type in Terminal `sudo xboxdrv --silent` if it's running by `systemctl`.

- Note: Print a list of supported devices:

`$ xboxdrv --list-supported-devices`

- If a controller have any problem in wine, follow [this website](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1438422/22-04-the-xbox-controller-of-wine-has-a-mistake-how-to-fix).

More info:

https://youtu.be/JfcSMRooHLU

https://github.com/gotbletu/shownotes/blob/master/xboxdrv.md