# Xboxdrv not able to start

Tags: xbox-one

I installed the xbox controller drivers (for use with an XBox One controller) using

```
sudo apt install xboxdrv
```

However when I try to start/enable the service with

```
sudo systemctl start xboxdrv.service
```

I get the following error

```
Failed to start xboxdrv.service: Unit xboxdrv.service not found.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to enable the service with the following command:

`sudo systemctl enable xboxdrv.service`

and then try starting it with:

`sudo systemctl start xboxdrv.service`

If the service is not found, then the service needs to be created.

Make a file called "xboxdrv.service" in the `/etc/systemd/system` and copy/paste the following in it:

```
[Unit]
Description=Xbox controller driver daemon

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
PIDFile=/var/run/xboxdrv.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/share/ubuntu-xboxdrv/xboxdrv-pre
EnvironmentFile=/usr/share/ubuntu-xboxdrv/uxvars
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xboxdrv --daemon --silent --pid-file /var/run/xboxdrv.pid --dbus disabled $XBOXDRV_OPTIONS $PAD_OPTIONS $CONTROLLER0_OPTIONS --next-controller $PAD_OPTIONS $CONTROLLER1_OPTIONS --next-controller $PAD_OPTIONS $CONTROLLER2_OPTIONS --next-controller $PAD_OPTIONS $CONTROLLER3_OPTIONS

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then enable the service:
`sudo systemctl enable xboxdrv.service`

Followed by starting the service:
`sudo systemctl start xboxdrv.service`

Make sure the Xbox controller is connected when you start the service.

Comment: You're a lifesaver, thanx! :D
Do you have any idea how I can connect my controller wirelessly, cause when I try to pair the device is says "Device not available", altho scanning does find it in console (not in GUI). Thanx again :D

Comment: I haven't tried to pair the controller over bluetooth. There are a few things to consider: is the controller a stock controller or a custom one (like the XBox Elite Controller)? Does the controller need to have a firmware update? Does the host computer need a kernel update? Try posting a new question.

Comment: Will do, thanx :D

Comment: @engineerRed, in Ubuntu 22.04, after creating a new file with the above text, then `enable` with my xbox controller connected, and then `start`, I got the error in the output: `Job for xboxdrv.service failed because of unavailable resources or another system error.
See "systemctl status xboxdrv.service" and "journalctl -xeu xboxdrv.service" for details.`

Comment: Check it out: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/aa/a4/64/aaa464720171cda6a208b54b782272f2.jpg

Comment: The image shows an error like "No such file or directory". Can you check that the file `/etc/systemd/system/xboxdrv.service` exists? Maybe there is a typo in the filename (or the file is located in a different directory).

Comment: @engineerRed, I'm pretty sure that the file `/etc/systemd/system/xboxdrv.service` already exists, I made it before! The problem is that the syntax of `ExecStart=` have many codes that It couldn't start `xboxdrv`, therefore I made a new answer below to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

**For Ubuntu 22.04:**

- Note #1: If you have followed the previous answer, first stop and then disable the `xboxdrv.service` before editing the existing file to fix by the following steps:

`$ sudo systemctl stop xboxdrv.service`

`$ sudo systemctl disable xboxdrv.service`

- Note #2: Before setting up the `systemctl` app, make sure if you have installed correctly the `xboxdrv` by the steps in [this website](https://askubuntu.com/questions/695069/xbox-controller-blinking/1438948#1438948).

1. Make a new file called "xboxdrv.service" in the directory `/etc/systemd/system` and copy/paste the following text in it:

```
[Unit]
Description=Xbox controller driver daemon
 
[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xboxdrv --silent
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2. Enable the service:

`$ sudo systemctl enable xboxdrv.service`

- Make sure the Xbox controller is connected before continuing the next steps.

3. Start the service:

`$ sudo systemctl start xboxdrv.service`

4. Check if `xboxdrv` is running by the service:

`$ sudo systemctl status xboxdrv.service` (Press "q" to end)

- Note #3: If you have forgotten to connect the controller before or the controller has been disconnected by accident and you have to reconnect it, just type:

`$ sudo systemctl restart xboxdrv.service`

- Note #4: If the previous command does not solve the problem to reconnect the controller, reboot the PC and try again.
- Note #5: It's not necessary to type in Terminal `sudo xboxdrv --silent` if the `xboxdrv` is running by the service, besides it runs every time when Ubuntu boots.