# How to set up xbox360 controller on Ubuntu 20.04 focal fossa

Tags: gamepad, xbox-360

I'm extremely new to Ubuntu and Linux in general and was looking for how to set up a wired xbox360 controller to my laptop running focal fossa. All that I found were either outdated or irrelevant. Tried installing xboxdrv from terminal and it lead to installing Timidity, which I uninstalled. I've also tried sc_controller and it hasn't worked. Just trying to get it running so I can have ease while using my laptop because the default trackpad sucks and I don't always have the space for my USB mouse.

Comment: Here is an explanation how to solve: https://askubuntu.com/questions/695069/xbox-controller-blinking/1438948#1438948

Answer (score 1):

I assume xpad driver is installed by default so try a different one.
Open a terminal and type
`sudo apt-get install xboxdrv`
Then to kick it in the guts type
`sudo xboxdrv --detach-kernel-driver`
You can get more help [here](https://xboxdrv.gitlab.io/)

Comment: Second command led to an invalid option -- e error. Typing xboxdrv leads to an error: usbcontroller::usbcontroller (): lisub open() failed:IBISB_ERROR_ACCESS

Comment: Instead of the detatch command try `sudo rmmod xpad` and then `sudo xboxdrv` and the manual is here http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/xboxdrv.1.html

Comment: Figured out it works if I use it in the gnome-terminal over just plain terminal