# Can't connect xbox360 controller to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gamepad, xbox-360

I can't connect the original Xbox 360 controller to my PC with a cable. I'm trying to follow this tutorial: https://askubuntu.com/a/1438948
First, i installed xboxdrv with

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:rael-gc/ubuntu-xboxdrv`

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-xboxdrv
```

Then i added xpad to a blacklist by editing the /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
Then i unload the module with`sudo rmmod xpad`
Then i remove `jstest-gtk` and reinstall it with

```
sudo apt-get purge jstest-gtk

sudo apt-get install xboxdrv

sudo apt-get install jstest-gtk
```

And made a file `/etc/default/xboxdrv` with following text in:

```
[xboxdrv]
silent = true

# controller 1
trigger-as-button = true
dpad-as-button = true
deadzone = 4000

# controller 2
next-controller = true
trigger-as-button = true
dpad-as-button = true
deadzone = 4000

# controller 3
next-controller = true
trigger-as-button = true
dpad-as-button = true
deadzone = 4000

# controller 4
next-controller = true
trigger-as-button = true
dpad-as-button = true
deadzone = 4000

[xboxdrv-daemon]
dbus = disabled
```

However, when I run sudo xboxdrv, I get the following output:

> xboxdrv 0.8.8 - [http://pingus.seul.org/~grumbel/xboxdrv/](http://pingus.seul.org/%7Egrumbel/xboxdrv/)  Copyright ©
> 2008-2011 Ingo Ruhnke grumbel@gmail.com  Licensed under GNU GPL
> version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html  This program
> comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  This is free software, and you are
> welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions; see the file
> COPYING for details.
>
> -- [ ERROR ] ------------------------------------------------------ No Xbox or Xbox360 controller found

Then I tried to follow this tutorial: https://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/558748653738497361/?l=french&ctp=6
And when I run `evtest /dev/input/eventxx` (i've tried all events from 0 to 16 with controller plugged in), nothing happens.

The `lsusb` command gives me this output:

```
Bus 003 Device 017: ID 045e:028f Microsoft Corp. Xbox360 Wireless Controller
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the elements of the solution you've tried in the post itself rather than relying on a link to the guide you followed. We need to understand what steps you took specifically and the error messages you got in the process as they will help us better diagnose your problem.

Comment: I apologize, I changed the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work because you have an Xbox 360 Wireless Controller and you're trying to connect it with the (poorly-named) Play & Charge Kit cable. The kit includes a rechargeable battery pack and allows the controller to be used (wirelessly) while charging the battery pack. The cable cannot be used to receive inputs. You'll need the Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver to use this controller.